# Why (remove child) not working even on direct parent-child relation?

Tags: javascript, get, getelementbyid, removechild

I was trying to run `removechild` on this HTML code:

But it gives me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

```js
let list = document.getElementById("cont");
list.removeChild(document.getElementById("heading"));
```

```html
<div class="container" id="cont">
  <h1 id="heading">Hello</h1>
  <h1>World</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/gvpnxk93/22/ the given code is working fine. thanks!

Comment: Seems to work in the snippet I made you

Comment: Runs without error for me